# Trapping errors in command substitution using "-o errtrace" (ie set -E)

Tags: bash, command-substitution

According to this [ref manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html):

> -E (also -o errtrace)
>
> If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment. The
>   ERR trap is normally not inherited in such cases.

However, I must be interpreting it wrongly, because the following does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# -*- bash -*-

set -e -o pipefail -o errtrace -o functrace

function boom {
  echo "err status: $?"
  exit $?
}
trap boom ERR


echo $( made up name )
echo "  ! should not be reached ! "
```

I already know simple assignment, `my_var=$(made_up_name)`, will exit the script with `set -e` (ie errexit).

Is  `-E/-o errtrace` supposed to work like the above code? Or, most likely, I misread it?

Comment: This is a good question. Replacing `echo $( made up name )` with `$( made up name )` produces the desired behaviour. I don't have an explanation though.

Comment: I don't know about bash's -E but I do know that -e only effects a shell exit if the error results from the last command in a pipeline. So your `var=$( pipe )` and `$( pipe )` examples would both represent pipe endpoints whereas `pipe > echo` would not. My man page says: 
"1. The  failure  of any individual command in a multi-command pipeline shall not cause the shell to exit.
                 Only the failure of the pipeline itself shall be considered.
"

Comment: You can make it fail though: echo $(${madeupname?}). But that's set -e. Again, -E is outside my own experience.

Comment: @mikeserv @1_CR The bash manual @[echo](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Builtins) indicates that `echo` always returns 0. This must be factored in the analysis...

Comment: @illiminE - exactly - it's the last in the pipeline so it won't fail, but the ${var?} if unset will fail unless it is considered to be explicitly tested - according to POSIX - with [ ] || && or similar because it qualifies as a test of its own. If you add ${var?error message} you'll get "error message">&2.

Comment: You want me to answer it? But I don't know what `set -E` does - I don't feel competent enough in the subject material to answer it. I know how to use `set -e` to make it fail with or without echo, but not the way it's asked. I was just offering advice. I'll give it a go - but delete it if it sucks, ok?

Comment: Ok, well, I refferred to the POSIX manual, but no, you don't need another command. It will kill the shell - see the V+N? It's the only command run when it is run... Also, every time the function is called the variable is evaluated alone - the `heredoc` is evaluated BEFORE the function runs. I'll demonstrate.

Comment: I added some stuff at the bottom. You can keep the bounty though - like I said, I don't know about bash -E.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get bash to exit on backtick failure in a similar way to pipefail?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23026/how-can-i-get-bash-to-exit-on-backtick-failure-in-a-similar-way-to-pipefail)

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev other than that this question contains a needless `-o pipefail` which "links" it to the other question, do you have any rationale to declare it a duplicate?

Comment: @mosvy both questions are asking how to make a command line that contains `$(command)` fail if `command` fails.

Comment: Distantly related: [How is the return status of a variable assignment determined?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/270828/80216)

Comment: This is kind of side talk, but at the line "exit $?", the "$?" has already become "0" because in the one line above it was cleared.
I think the question should be improved so that the value of $? should be kept in a variable before using it in this case.
It's a common pitfall and it may obscure original intention of the question.

Answer (score 5):

*Note: `zsh` will complain about "bad patterns" if you don't configure it to accept "inline comments" for most of the examples here and don't run them through a proxy shell as I have done with `sh <<-\CMD`.*

Ok, so, as I stated in the comments above, I don't know specifically about *bash's `set -E`*, but I know that POSIX compatible shells provide a simple means of testing a value if you desire it:

```
    sh -evx <<-\CMD
    _test() { echo $( ${empty:?error string} ) &&\
        echo "echo still works" 
    }
    _test && echo "_test doesnt fail"
    # END
    CMD
sh: line 1: empty: error string
+ echo

+ echo 'echo still works'
echo still works
+ echo '_test doesnt fail'
_test doesnt fail
```

Above you'll see that though I used *`parameter expansion`* to test *`${empty?} _test()`* still  *`return`s* a pass - as is evinced in the last *`echo`* This occurs because the failed value kills the *`$( command substitution )`* subshell that contains it, but its parent shell - *`_test`* at this time - keeps on trucking. And *`echo`* doesn't care - it's plenty happy to serve only a *`\newline; echo`* is ***not*** a test.

But consider this:

```
    sh -evx <<-\CMD
    _test() { echo $( ${empty:?error string} ) &&\
            echo "echo still works" ; } 2<<-INIT
            ${empty?function doesnt run}
    INIT
    _test ||\
            echo "this doesnt even print"
    # END
    CMD
_test+ sh: line 1: empty: function doesnt run
```

Because I fed *`_test()'s`* input with a pre-evaluated parameter in the *`INIT here-document`* now the *`_test()`* function doesn't even attempt to run at all. What's more the *`sh`* shell apparently gives up the ghost entirely and *`echo "this doesnt even print"` **doesn't even print.***

Probably that is ***not*** what you want.

This happens because the *`${var?}`* style parameter-expansion is ***designed to quit the `shell`*** in the event of a missing parameter, it [works like this](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02):

> ***`${parameter:?[word]}`***
>
> > Indicate Error if **`Null`** or **`Unset.`** If parameter is unset or null, the *`expansion of word`* (or a message indicating it is unset if word is omitted) shall be *`written to standard error`* and the ***`shell exits with a non-zero exit status`.*** Otherwise, the value of *`parameter shall be substituted`.* An interactive shell need not exit.

I won't copy/paste the entire document, but if you want a failure for a **`set but null`** value you use the form:

> *`${var` **:?** `error message }`*

With the *`:colon`* as above. If you want a *`null`* value to succeed, just omit the colon. You can also negate it and fail only for set values, as I'll show in a moment.

Another run of *`_test():`*

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    _test() { echo $( ${empty:?error string} ) &&\
            echo "echo still works" ; } 2<<-INIT
            ${empty?function doesnt run}
    INIT
    echo "this runs" |\
        ( _test ; echo "this doesnt" ) ||\
            echo "now it prints"
    # END
    CMD
this runs
sh: line 1: empty: function doesnt run
now it prints
```

This works with all kinds of quick tests, but above you'll see that *`_test()`*, run from the middle of the *`pipeline`* fails, and in fact its containing *`command list`* subshell fails entirely, as none of the commands within the function run nor the following *`echo`* run at all, though it is also shown that it can easily be tested because *`echo "now it prints"` **now prints.***

The devil is in the details, I guess. In the above case, the shell that exits is *not* the script's *`_main | logic | pipeline`* but the ***`( subshell in which we ${test?} ) ||`*** so a little sandboxing is called for.

And it may not be obvious, but if you wanted to only pass for the opposite case, or only *`set=`* values, it's fairly simple as well:

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    N= #N is NULL
    _test=$N #_test is also NULL and
    v="something you would rather do without"    
    ( #this subshell dies
        echo "v is ${v+set}: and its value is ${v:+not NULL}"
        echo "So this ${_test:-"\$_test:="} will equal ${_test:="$v"}"
        ${_test:+${N:?so you test for it with a little nesting}}
        echo "sure wish we could do some other things"
    )
    ( #this subshell does some other things 
        unset v #to ensure it is definitely unset
        echo "But here v is ${v-unset}: ${v:+you certainly wont see this}"
        echo "So this ${_test:-"\$_test:="} will equal NULL ${_test:="$v"}"
        ${_test:+${N:?is never substituted}}
        echo "so now we can do some other things" 
    )
    #and even though we set _test and unset v in the subshell
    echo "_test is still ${_test:-"NULL"} and ${v:+"v is still $v"}"
    # END
    CMD
v is set: and its value is not NULL
So this $_test:= will equal something you would rather do without
sh: line 7: N: so you test for it with a little nesting
But here v is unset:
So this $_test:= will equal NULL
so now we can do some other things
_test is still NULL and v is still something you would rather do without
```

The above example takes advantage of all 4 forms of POSIX parameter substitution and their various *`:colon null`* or *`not null`* tests. There is more information in the link above, and [here it is again](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02).

And I guess we should show our ***`_test`*** function work, too, right? We just declare ***`empty=something`*** as a parameter to our function (or any time beforehand):

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    _test() { echo $( echo ${empty:?error string} ) &&\
            echo "echo still works" ; } 2<<-INIT
            ${empty?tested as a pass before function runs}
    INIT
    echo "this runs" >&2 |\
        ( empty=not_empty _test ; echo "yay! I print now!" ) ||\
            echo "suspiciously quiet"
    # END
    CMD
this runs
not_empty
echo still works
yay! I print now!
```

It should be noted that this evaluation stands alone - it requires no additional test to fail. A couple more examples:

```
    sh <<-\CMD
    empty= 
    ${empty?null, no colon, no failure}
    unset empty
    echo "${empty?this is stderr} this is not"
    # END
    CMD
sh: line 3: empty: this is stderr

    sh <<-\CMD
    _input_fn() { set -- "$@" #redundant
            echo ${*?WHERES MY DATA?}
            #echo is not necessary though
            shift #sure hope we have more than $1 parameter
            : ${*?WHERES MY DATA?} #: do nothing, gracefully
    }
    _input_fn heres some stuff
    _input_fn one #here
    # shell dies - third try doesnt run
    _input_fn you there?
    # END
    CMD
heres some stuff
one
sh: line :5 *: WHERES MY DATA?
```

And so finally we come back to the original question : ***how to handle errors in a `$(command substitution)` subshell?*** The truth is - there are two ways, but neither is direct. The core of the problem is the shell's evaluation process - shell expansions (including *`$(command substitution)`*) happen earlier in the shell's evaluation process than does current shell command execution - which is when your errors could be caught and trapped.

The issue the op experiences is that by the time the current shell evaluates for errors, the *`$(command substitution)`* subshell has already been substituted away - no errors remain.

So what are the two ways? Either you do it explicitly within the *`$(command substitution)`* subshell with tests as you would without it, or you absorb its results into a current shell variable and test its value.

#### Method 1:

```
    echo "$(madeup && echo \: || echo '${fail:?die}')" |\
          . /dev/stdin

sh: command not found: madeup
/dev/stdin:1: fail: die

    echo $?

126
```

#### Method 2:

```
    var="$(madeup)" ; echo "${var:?die} still not stderr"

sh: command not found: madeup
sh: var: die

    echo $?

1
```

This
will fail regardless of the number of variables declared per line:

```
   v1="$(madeup)" v2="$(ls)" ; echo "${v1:?}" "${v2:?}"

sh: command not found: madeup
sh: v1: parameter not set
```

And our return value remains constant:

```
    echo $?
1
```

#### NOW THE TRAP:

```
    trap 'printf %s\\n trap resurrects shell!' ERR
    v1="$(madeup)" v2="$(printf %s\\n shown after trap)"
    echo "${v1:?#1 - still stderr}" "${v2:?invisible}"

sh: command not found: madeup
sh: v1: #1 - still stderr
trap
resurrects
shell!
shown
after
trap

    echo $?
0
```

Comment: For instance, practically his exact specification: echo ${v=$( madeupname )} ; echo "${v:?trap1st} ! is not reached !"

Comment: To summarize: These parameter expansions are a great way to control if variables are set etc. In respect of the exit status of echo, I noticed that `echo "abc" "${v1:?}"` doesn't seem to execute(abc never printed). And the shell returns 1. This is true with or without a command even(`"${v1:?}"` directly on the cli). But for OP's script, all that was required to trigger the trap is placing his variable assignment containing a substitution for a nonexistent command alone on a single line. Otherwise the behavior of echo is to return 0 always, unless interrupted like with the tests you explained.

Comment: Just `v=$( madeup )`. I don't see what is unsafe with that. It's just an assignment, the person mispelled the command for instance `v="$(lss)"`. It errors. Yes you can verify with the error status of the last command $? - because it is the command on the line (an assignment with no command name) and nothing else - not an argument to echo. Plus, here it's trapped by the function as !=0, so you get feedback twice. Otherwise surely as you explain there is a better way to do this orderly within a framework but OP had 1 single line: an echo plus his failed substitution. He was wondering about echo.

Comment: Yes, simple assignment is mentioned in the question as well as a for granted, and while i couldnt offer specific advice on how to make use of -E, i did try to show similar results to the demonstrated issue were more than possible without resorting to bashisms. In any case, it is specifically the issues you mention - like single assignment per line - that make such solutions difficult to handle in a pipeline, which i also demonstrated how to handle. Though it's true what you say - ***there is nothing unsafe about simply assigning it.***

Comment: Good point - perhaps more effort is called for. Ill think on it.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a bug in bash.  During the Command Substitution step in

```
echo $( made up name )
```

`made` runs (or fails to be found) in a subshell, but the subshell is "optimized" in such a way that it doesn't use some traps from the parent shell.  This was fixed in [version 4.4.5](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.4-patches/bash44-005):

> Under certain circumstances, a simple command is optimized to eliminate a
>   fork, resulting in an EXIT trap not being executed.

With bash 4.4.5 or higher, you should see the following output:

```
error.sh: line 13: made: command not found
err status: 127
  ! should not be reached !
```

The trap handler has been called as expected, then the subshell exits.  (`set -e` only causes the subshell to exit, not the parent, so that "should not be reached" message should, in fact, be reached.)

A workaround for older versions is to force the creation of a full, non-optimized subshell:

```
echo $( ( made up name ) )
```

The extra spaces are [required](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_03) to distinguish from Arithmetic Expansion.

Answer (score 2):

> If set, any trap on ERR is inherited by shell functions, command substitutions, and commands executed in a subshell environment

In your script its a command execution(`echo $( made up name )`). In bash commands are delimited with either *;* or with *new line*. In the command

```
echo $( made up name )
```

`$( made up name )` is considered as a part of the command. Even if this part fails and return with error, the whole command executes successfully as `echo` don't know about it. As the command return with 0 no trap triggered.

You need to put it in two commands, assignment and echo

```
var=$(made_up_name)
echo $var
```

Comment: `echo $var` doesn't fail - `$var` is expanded to empty before ever `echo` actually gets a look at it.