# Default function arguments (manually emitting bash psuedo-signals)

Tags: bash, arguments, trap

I'm looking for a solution that will automatically allow me to call a function with specific parameters in a certain situation.
Here is the specific scenario:

When an error occurs, I can set up my error handler like this:

```
function _trap_err () {
    echo "An error occurred in "$1":"$2" on "$3":"$4".
}
```

And I can set the trap to collect the debugging data I need automatically – **at the correct moment in execution**.

```
trap '_trap_err "$BASH_SOURCE" "$BASH_LINENO" "$FUNCNAME" "$BASH_COMMAND" ' ERR
```

AFAIK, this only works when bash detects an error and emits the signal.

I'd like to extend this behavior so that I can manually signal an error when a check fails, for example, when checking function arguments:

```
# Usage: myfunc <requiredarg>
function myfunc () {
    [[ $# != 1 ]] && emit_err_signal
}
```

If there is a way to manually emit that error signal, then its possible to automatically collect that debugging argument at the correct time in execution to provide meaningful debugging information.

The alternative is to simply display an error message – which has to be hardcoded in every check – and doesn't display where the error occurred.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**
I should have specified that I this is for my .bashrc files and I don't want them to quit, I just want debugging information. Traps may have be overkill for this, i think the following solution may work:

```
function _debug () {
    local _message=${1:-""}
    printf "\e[1;32m[BASHRC] DEBUG: %-20s - %s\e[0m\n" "$BASH_SOURCE:$BASH_LINENO" "$_message"
}

_debug "Testing debug message."

> [BASHRC] DEBUG: .bashrc.d/bashrc:18  - Testing debug message.
```

Comment: `( ${unset?$(_function_call arg)} )` will kill only the subshell in which is called and still emit a message to `stderr`. Please read this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/81457/trapping-errors-in-command-substitution-using-o-errtrace-ie-set-e/120008#120008

Answer (score 0):

You can use exit code :

```
set -e
# Usage: myfunc <requiredarg>
ARGS_NUM_ERROR=50
function myfunc () {
    [[ $# != 1 ]] && exit $ARGS_NUM_ERROR
}
```

Then you can trap `ARGS_NUM_ERROR` in your script with the suitable treatment.

Comment: `set -e` makes dangerous assumptions - specifically that all non-zero `exit` codes are failures. In this case it is useful, but probably moreso if placed within the body of the function than without it.

Comment: I should have specified in this in the question - in this case I'm trying to add some debugging information to my .bashrc file. I'm attempting to modularize it - putting specific chunks of configuration into .bashrc.d/conf.d & different utilities into .bashrc.d/lib.d - so I don't want the shell to exit if the error occurs, I'm just trying add some generic debugging information that can be toggle on/off with a flag.

Comment: I'm currently trying to figure out if the DEBUG trap can be used for this purpose - perhaps setting the DEBUG trap and then when I want to display a specific line, I would wrap a function call with something like _debug, which sets a flag, then the debug trap would echo the line and disable the flag.

Comment: @nfarrar - what of that other answer I wrote for you? `${unset?$(_function_call arg)}` should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

The `ERR` trap is triggered for any command with a nonzero exit status. There's no need for further explicit action to cause it to run.

```
function _trap_err () {
  echo "An error occurred in $1:$2 on $3:$4."
}
trap '_trap_err "$BASH_SOURCE" "$BASH_LINENO" "$FUNCNAME" "$BASH_COMMAND" ' ERR

foo () {
    false
}

foo
echo "Some commands that succeed"
foo
```