# Command substitution inside a function does not stop the script on a failure even if -e is set

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a following script `sandbox.sh`,

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu -o pipefail -E

function func1() {
  echo "FUNC1"
  exit 1
}

function func2() {
  local ret
  ret=$(func1)
  echo $ret
  echo "(func2)This line shouldn't be reached:'${?}'" >&2
}

var=$(func1) # The Line
echo "main:This line shouldn't be reached:'${var}':'${?}'" >&2
```

(GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu))

This stops executing expectedly,

```
$ bash -eu sandbox.sh 
$
```

However, if I modify "The Line" to `var=$(func2)` to call `func1` through `func2`, it will give me following output

```
$ bash sandbox.sh 
(func2)This line shouldn't be reached:'0'
main:This line shouldn't be reached:'FUNC1':'0'
$
```

To me, it seems command substitution behaves differently when it is placed inside a function, but I don't see why bash is designed so.
Also it is a quite possible situation where a function's output is used by another and such a difference is confusing.

NOTE: If I rewrite func2 like following,

```
function func2() {
  func1
}
```

The script stops at The Line.
However, programmers quite often want to manipulate output from func1, I believe.

Comment: This has nothing to do with functions, but with subshells (ie with your `$(...)` command substitutions). `set -e / -o errexit` is not inherited in subshells. Simpler example: `bash -c 'set -e; echo $(false; echo survived)'`. If you had used `var=$(set -e; func2)` in "The Line", the "shouldn't be reached" lines wouldn't have been reached.

Comment: Another option is to add `shopt -s inherit_errexit` at the beginning of your script (also enabled in posix mode). Notice that `set -e / errexit` is independent of the `ERR` trap and is not affected by `set -E / errtrace`

Comment: @mosvy, 
Thanks, ```set -e``` made my script work as intended.
But it also made puzzled me a bit more.
Why don't I need to add ```set -e``` to the line that performs command substitution in ```func2```?

Comment: because `func1` calls `exit 1`, causing the subshell to exit with a non-zero status, which will also be the exit status of `ret=$(func1)`.

Comment: Ah! and ```func2``` that contains ```ret=$(func1)``` is executed in a shell whose ```-e``` is set at The Line.

Comment: I think ```shopt -s inherit_errexit``` should be considered sort of "best practice".
Because otherwise we cannot reuse functions reliably.
To my memory, I have never seen web sites that introduces the technique as a popular good practice.
Is there any reason for that? Or any drawbacks?

Comment: imho, `set -e` is too tricky to be used reliably -- the basic idea behind it is right, but the implementation is [lousy](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/) (no, I haven't checked the correctness of those tables! ;-)).

Comment: @mosvy, note that `inherit_errexit` is on when `bash` is running as `sh`. I wouldn't say the _idea is right_, I'm not sure it could ever be implemented with a clear and consistent API. To me, it's better avoided, reserved for the most basic of scripts (i.e. with the real-life definition of script, when you just put in a file a plain sequence of commands run one after the other).

Comment: @Kusalananda the answers to the purported dupe in no way address `set -e` not being inherited in subshells in bash, `inherit_errexit` being a workaround for it, it being the default in posix mode, or the pitfalls of `set -e` in general.

Comment: @mosvy You mentioned in a flagging message that I put this question on hold in order to reduce its visibility. This is not so. I put it on hold because I honestly thought it was a duplicate. I'm reopening it now because I believe that you may have a good answer for this question.

Answer (score 6):

This is all perfectly understandable if we step through slowly.
Some more logging is required,
so run *bash* with the `-x` parameter,
which will echo commands just before bash executes them,
prefixed by `+` .

## First run

```
$ bash -x sandbox.sh; echo $?
+ set -eu -o pipefail -E
++ func1
++ echo FUNC1
++ exit 1
+ var=FUNC1
1
```

- `-e` says *this* shell will exit immediately a command returns non-zero.
  Crucially though, you run `func1` in a subshell (using `$(` `)`).
  The trace above shows this fact by using two `+`s as the prefix (`++` ).
- The subshell spits out `FUNC1` on stdout, and then exits with return code 1.

  - Note: `-e` is off inside this subshell. The reason the subshell quit was due to the `exit` command, not `-e`. You can't really tell this due to the way `func1` is written.
- Back in the first shell, we assign `FUNC1` to the variable *var*. However, the exit code of this assignment command **is the exit code of the last command substitution**. *Bash* sees this failure (i.e., non-zero exit code), and quits.

To quote the manual's *SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION* section:

> If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of  the  command  is the exit status of the last command substitution performed.

## Second run

Exactly the same explanation as the first run.
We note again that the `-e` is not in effect inside the subshell.
This time however,
there is a material difference — we get a clearer view of what is happening.

- The exit code of `func2` is the exit code of its last command
- That `echo` always  succeeds.
- `func2` always succeeds
- The assignment always succeeds.

`-e` has no effect.

## `shopt -s inherit_errexit` ?

This will turn on `-e` in subshells.
It is however a difficult bedfellow.
It does not guarantee we assert when a command fails.

Consider this:

```
set -e
shopt -s inherit_errexit

f() { echo a; (exit 22); echo b; }

echo "f says [$(f)] $?"
echo byee
```

This time the command substitution is part of an `echo`, rather than an assignment, and we get

```
+ set -e
+ shopt -s inherit_errexit
++ f
++ echo a
++ exit 22
+ echo 'f says [a] 22'
f says [a] 22
+ echo byee
byee
```

- The subshell sees a command that fails with exit code 22. Since `-e` is in effect, the shell exits with code 22 (`echo b` does not execute).
- Back in the first shell, `echo` gets `a` as the output of `f`, and `22` as the exit code of the subshell
- Thing is, unlike an assignment, the exit code of the `echo` is zero.

## Version

```
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```