# Nested command substitution does not stop a script on a failure even if -e and shopt -s inherit_errexit are set

Tags: bash, shell-script, subshell

Suppose you have a following script `sandbox.sh`.

(This looks similar to [Command substitution inside a function does not stop the script on a failure even if -e is set](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541682/command-substitution-inside-a-function-does-not-stop-the-script-on-a-failure-eve), but I believe a bit different one)

At "The Line", I am trying to pass an output from `func2` to `func1` as a positional parameter.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu -o pipefail -E
shopt -s inherit_errexit

function func1() {
  local arg="${1}"
  echo "(func1)This line shouldn't be reached:arg='${arg}': '${?}'" >&2
}

function func2() {
  echo "value from func2"
  exit 1
}

var="$(func1 "$(func2)")" # The Line
echo "main:This line shouldn't be reached:var='${var}':'${?}'" >&2
```

This is a possible situation, where a programmer desires to construct a data by reusing existing functions in a concise manner, I believe.

However, this results in following output.

```
$ bash sandbox.sh 
(func1)This line shouldn't be reached:arg='value from func2': '0'
main:This line shouldn't be reached:var='':'0'
$
```

I interpreted this behavior that the sub-shell that invokes `func2` is not inheriting `errexit` behaviour from the sub-shell for `func1`.
Thus, `func1` takes unset value as its argument.

I tried to make it work intendedly by modifying "The Line", like

```
# A.
var="$(set -e; func1 "$(set -e; func2)")" # The Line
```

Or

```
# B.
var="$(func1 "$(func2 || exit 1)" || exit 1)" # The Line
```

But no luck yet.
Actually, I am puzzled at neither A. nor B. not fixing the behavior.
What is a best practice for this?
Or shouldn't I attempt to nest command substitutions from the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Based on an answer so far (, which seems to be deleted) and experiments I made, I came to think that this (nested command substitution) should only be considered a 'bad practice' or a at best 'very cumbersome'.

The best I could do is

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu -o pipefail -E
shopt -s inherit_errexit

function func1() {
  [[ $? == 0 ]]; return 1 # The boilerplate line
  local arg="${1}"
  echo "(func1)This line shouldn't be reached:arg='${arg}': '${?}'" >&2
}

function func2() {
  echo "value from func2"
  return 1
}

var="$(func1 "$(func2)")" # The line
echo "main:This line shouldn't be reached:var='${var}':'${?}'" >&2
```

This results in an expected output (empty) and non-zero (1) exit code.
The trick is to check if the `$?` is `0` at the first line in a definition of function.
And this (The boilerplate line) needs to be inserted for every function definition that is reused in 'nested command substitution'.
If you want to use 'the nested command substitution' syntax without becoming anxious, you need to familiarize yourself with inserting the boilerplate every time you create a new function.

And is 'The boilerplate line' really harmless? Apparently, yes, I believe.
Since if you `set -eu`, an immediate abortion is expected whenever a failure is detected, either way.
But I'm not good at bash programming and maybe missing some potential pitfall.
I really would like to know more experienced people's insights.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider `echo "$(false)"`; functions are irrelevant to the general issue. This example also shows that nested command-replacement isn't necessary to experience the issue.

Comment: Nested command substitution is not a bad practice. It's just that all this `set -euo pipefail; shopt -s inherit_errexit` is a questionable thing. [No good solution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). Although [some](https://saveriomiroddi.github.io/Additional-shell-options-for-non-trivial-bash-shell-scripts/) recommend it. No generally accepted opinion as well. As for the boilerplate code, that sounds like a bad practice.