# how to fail on first error when using bash as a template tool

Tags: bash, error-handling, template

I am looking for a better version of `set -e`. That better version should just work™. I briefly read [BashFaq/105](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105) and tried [this insane approach](https://fvue.nl/wiki/Bash:_Error_handling#Solutions_revisited:_Combining_the_tools), but I still do not know how to fail on error.

My use case is that I would like to generate a text file from a template like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# none of these options helped to get the behavior I want: stop on first error
# set -euo pipefail
# shopt -s inherit_errexit
# set -o errexit
# trap ERR

cat <<< "
MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=$(pwgen -1 32)

MYAPP_USER_PASSWORD=$(pwgen -1 8)

MYAPP_CONFIGURATION_DATE=$(date --utc --iso-8601=ns)
"
```

Alternatively, [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2914220/2615118) is also acceptable to me (where `template.txt` is a text file that contains the [here string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html#Here-Strings) from above):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# none of these options helped to get the behavior I want: stop on first error
# set -euo pipefail
# shopt -s inherit_errexit
# set -o errexit
# trap ERR

while read line; do
    [ -z "$line" ] || echo "# $line"
    cmd="echo $line"
    outline=$(eval $cmd)
    exitstatus=$?
    echo "$outline"
    echo "# exit status was $exitstatus"
done < "template.txt"
```

Unfortunately, neither of the above perfectly works for me because of the following requirement: I just want the whole thing to crash if a command substitution fails, e.g., due to `pwgen` not being found. There should be no more than one error.

With other techniques the desired behavior is the default:

```
# this is an erb file                    
<%
require 'securerandom'
require 'date'
%>

MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD=<%= SecureRandom.alphanumeric(32) %>

MYAPP_USER_PASSWORD=<%= SecureRandom.alphanumeric(8) %>

MYAPP_CONFIGURATION_DATE=<%= DateTime.now.new_offset.iso8601(6) %>
```

if there is a typo in `SecureRandom` then `erb` immediately exits with a failure.

**How to achieve this crash-on-failure behavior with bash?**

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use a configuration tool like [Ansible](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/index.html) which allow you to use jinja2 [templates](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html), and also allow you to verify the resulting file if the application which consume the file have some sort of config check.

```
- name: Update sshd configuration safely, avoid locking yourself out
  template:
    src: etc/ssh/sshd_config.j2
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0600'
    validate: /usr/sbin/sshd -t -f %s
    backup: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

After [some more research](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/609532/449147) I prefer an `erb`-like solution over the bash template. If there is a fail-fast solution for bash then it is too exotic to be useful (simplicity, clarity, maintainability, ...).

All my attempts on a simple fail-fast bash solution were negated by the following rule concerning [bash's Simple Command Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Simple-Command-Expansion.html#Simple-Command-Expansion):

> If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed.

TL;DR: Forget that bash-template idea because it is too complicated to be useful. Instead, choose a high-level tool that was designed for that job.